# lapply with condition?

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-tables, lapply

I try to do a function which works with for loops with lapply instead. I am very new to R and not confortable with lapply. I especially don't get how to make an "if" condition.

My current code with for loops looks like that (it nomalizes volume series):

```
function(TableVolume,VolumeM,VolumeStD,n){
TableBN = TableVolume[n:nrow(TableVolume),]

for(k in 1:nrow(TableBN)){for (i in 2:ncol(TableBN)){if(!is.na(VolumeM[k,i]) && (VolumeM[k,i]) && (TableVolume[n-1+k,i]>VolumeM[k,i]+1.96/sqrt(n)*VolumeStD[k,i])){TableBN[k,i]=TableVolume[n-1+k,i]/VolumeM[k,i]}else{TableBN[k,i]=0}}}
TableBN=TableBN[n:nrow(TableVolume),]
return(TableBN)
}
```

I know from [Apply over two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557652/r-apply-over-two-data-frames) how to do a function that works with 2 data frame but I still don't see how to handle tests.

Thanks for your support,
Vincent

Comment: found that: stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/277193.html

Comment: I am working on:

    binarisation=function(TableVolume,VolumeM,VolumeStD,n)                          {lapply(TableVolume,function(h){lapply(VolumeM,function(u){

            lapply(VolumeStD,function(v,n){

            f(h,u,v,n)=h/(u+1.96*v/sqrt(n))

                        })

            })

            })

            }

            

            WorkingTable=binarisation(TableVolume,VolumeM,VolumeStD,n)

            

            remplissage=function(WorkingTable){lapply(WorkingTable,function(u){

            function(u)=max(u-1,0)

            })}

Which I try to have working

Answer (score 0):

You need use `lapply` (or other apply family function). It is generally required when you have some non-vectorized function to apply to vectorized argument. Your function and conditions is a combinations of arithmetic functions, which are nicely vectorized. So you can use subsetting and `ifelse` function please see as below:

```
set.seed(123)

# simulation
TableBN <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
VolumeM <- matrix(12:1, nrow = 3)
VolumeStD <- matrix(12:1, nrow = 3)
TableVolume <- matrix(abs(rnorm(10)), nrow = 5)


# function
f <- function(TableVolume, VolumeM, VolumeStD, n){
  TableBN <- TableVolume[n:nrow(TableVolume), ]

  ifelse(
    test = !is.na(VolumeM) && VolumeM && TableBN[, -1] > (VolumeM + 1.96 / sqrt(n) * VolumeStD), 
    yes = TableBN[, -1] / VolumeM,
    no = 0)
}

# Test
f(TableVolume, VolumeM, VolumeStD, 3)
```

Output:

```
0
```